# Html how to display anchor as block and have it centered in same line

Tags: html, css, anchor

I am trying to use an anchor element to display a block. When I do this all the anchor elements are listed from top to bottom, not all in the same line. I know I can fix this with float left/right, but I want to align it all in the center. Here is my html

```
<nav id="navigation">
    <a id="navigation-anchor-normal" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
    <a id="navigation-anchor-normal" href="plugins.html">Plugins</a>
    <a id="navigation-anchor-current" href="home.html">Home</a>
    <a id="navigation-anchor-normal" href="games.html">Games</a>
    <a id="navigation-anchor-normal" href="donate.html">Donate</a>
</nav>
```

Here is my CSS for this

```
#navigation {
    text-align:center;
}
#navigation-anchor-normal {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:aqua;
    display:block;
    padding:10px 15px;
}
#navigation-anchor-current {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:aqua;
    display:block;
    padding:10px 15px;
}
```

Is there anyway I can center these anchor elements on the same line?

Comment: #navigation-anchor-normal { display:inline-block; }

Comment: Thank you! Solved the problem for me :).

Comment: I thought u needed it as block

Comment: inline-block seems to work just as fine as a block, but displays all in the same line. I am new to CSS, I was just looking for something like that. Sorry for not clearly mentioning that above.

Answer (score 0):

Put float: left on the #navigation-anchor-current & #navigation-anchor-normal then edit the container box styling to center all the text

Fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/uhyu3dsy/

```
#navigation {
text-align:center;
}
#navigation-anchor-normal {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:aqua;
    display:block;
    padding:10px 15px;
    float:left;
}
#navigation-anchor-current {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:aqua;
    display:block;
    padding:10px 15px;
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: Do you really know what float:left actually does?

Answer (score 0):

Let me know this is your requirement

```css
#navigation {
    text-align:center;
    display:inline;  <!-- changes here -->
}
#navigation-anchor-normal {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:aqua;
    display:block;
    padding:10px 15px;
  display:inline;   <!-- changes here -->
}
#navigation-anchor-current {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:aqua;
    display:block;
    padding:10px 15px;
   display:inline;   <!-- changes here -->
}
```

```html
<nav id="navigation">
    <a id="navigation-anchor-normal" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
    <a id="navigation-anchor-normal" href="plugins.html">Plugins</a>
    <a id="navigation-anchor-current" href="home.html">Home</a>
    <a id="navigation-anchor-normal" href="games.html">Games</a>
    <a id="navigation-anchor-normal" href="donate.html">Donate</a>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Semantically, the navigation element should be a list of navigation element items.
Also, it is generally "good" practice to stray away from using CSS id's (#) unless absolutely necessary.

```css
#navigation ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#navigation li {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
}

#navigation a {
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: aqua; /* ewww aqua */
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
}

/* the active nav element can be changed to signify that it is actually active */
#navigation .active {
  color: grey;
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML white space can sometimes get rendered and cause unwanted results.
Using comments can help prevent this. -->

<nav id="navigation">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contacts</a></li><!-- 
    --><li><a href="plugins.html">Plugin</a></li><!--
    --><li><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a></li><!--
    --><li><a href="games.html">Games</a></li><!--
    --><li><a href="donate.html">Donate</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```